# Automated slow scroll with ScrollView

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to make a Text in a ScrollView scroll automatically, slowly enough to be able to read it

I already tried scrollToEnd, but the duration option is deprecated.
I also tried doing it with scrollTo and slowly increasing the y offset, but it's not that good.
Maybe I could do it by simulating the user scrolling, but I have no idea how.

```
startStopScrolling() {
    if (this.state.scrolling == false) {
      this.setState(state => ({ scrolling: true }));
      let that = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.state.scrolling == true) {
          this.state.scrollOf = this.state.scrollOf + 1;
          this.ref.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: this.state.scrollOf, animated: true });
        }
      }, 10);
    } else {
      this.setState(state => ({ scrolling: false }));
      this.state.scrollOf = 0;
    }
  }
```

```
            <ScrollView
              ref={data => {
                this.ref = data;
              }}
            >
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  this.startStopScrolling();
                }}
              >
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 25
                  }}
                >
                  {this.props.navigation.state.params.text}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created expo snack working example:
https://snack.expo.io/HyI0QBm_r

Comment: That is almost the same thing that I have done, as I said with scrollTo it doesn't look very good

Comment: i updated the demo without setInterval : https://snack.expo.io/BJrnEu7OB